# Add .php extension with URLs Using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect my website URLs with .php extension currently all URLs are opening with and without .php

**example**

```
https://www.ranglerz.com/about.php
https://www.ranglerz.com/about
```

The both URLs are working now but I want if user open `https://www.ranglerz.com/about` it will redirect to `https://www.ranglerz.com/about.php`

here is my **htaccess code**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I've tried all solutions that provided in different threads but nothing is working with this problem.

Comment: If you want to redirect the user, then you need to do that. Currently you only rewrite the requests internally. Please read the documentation of apaches rewriting module: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options -MultiViews

# Redirect to .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: using both conditions. I'm only getting URLs without extension

Comment: but i can use it without .php extension. Thanks for it

Comment: can you please guide me the purpose of  "Options -MultiViews" line in this condition

Comment: The Apache [docs on mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html), describes what the Multiviews Option does, when enabled (what you should avoid in your case).