# Error ModRewrite in htaccess. URL 404 Error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to force .php extension from htaccess, because someone changed it and now all my URLs give 404 error. Can somebody help me? If you wanna I can publish the `.htaccess`. I've also tried Mike solution, but everything stays without .php extension and 404 error.

Also i tried to modify it from the PHP archives but the same error appears.

```
# It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows ...
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews

# Redirect to .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [R=301,L]
# Mod_rewrite in use.
RewriteEngine On
    
    # Mod_rewrite in use.
    RewriteEngine On
    # SEGUIMOS
    Redirect 301 /si-no-queda-satisfecho-le-devolvemos-el-dinero.html https://www.academiapinto.es/otros-enlaces/si-no-queda-satisfecho-le-devolvemos-el-dinero.php
    Redirect 301 /si-no-queda-satisfecho-le-devolvemos-el-dinero.php https://www.academiapinto.es/otros-enlaces/si-no-queda-satisfecho-le-devolvemos-el-dinero.php
    
    # Redirect 301 / https://www.academiapinto.es/
    
    #parche POLILLA
    
    Redirect 301 /temario-Guardias-Jovenes-(Polillas).php https://www.academiapinto.es/oposiciones-de-ingreso-Colegio-Guardias-Jovenes-Duque-de-Ahumada.php
    
    Redirect 301 /blog-academia-pinto-para-preparar-tus-oposiciones-para-la-PN.php https://www.academiapinto.es/blog/articulo-academia-pinto-para-preparar-tus-oposiciones-para-la-PN.php
    Redirect 301 /blog-camino-a-baeza.php https://www.academiapinto.es/blog/articulo-camino-a-baeza.php
    Redirect 301 /blog-como-seleccionar-una-buena-academia-de-oposiciones-para-guardia-civil-y-policia-nacional.php https://www.academiapinto.es/blog/articulo-como-seleccionar-una-buena-academia-de-oposiciones-para-guardia-civil-y-policia-nacional.php
    Redirect 301 /blog-dime-como-estudias.php https://www.academiapinto.es/blog/articulo-dime-como-estudias.php
    Redirect 301 /blog-documentacion-instancia-oposicion-ingreso-a-la-guardia-civil.php https://www.academiapinto.es/blog/articulo-documentacion-instancia-oposicion-ingreso-a-la-guardia-civil.php
    Redirect 301 /blog-llego-la-hora.php https://www.academiapinto.es/blog/articulo-llego-la-hora.php
    Redirect 301 /blog-primer-concurso-de-fotografia.php https://www.academiapinto.es/blog/articulo-primer-concurso-de-fotografia.php
    Redirect 301 /blog-psicotecnicos-recomendaciones-necesarias.php https://www.academiapinto.es/blog/articulo-psicotecnicos-recomendaciones-necesarias.php
    Redirect 301 /blog-que-no-puedes-olvidar-en-tu-examen-para-la-guardia-civil.php https://www.academiapinto.es/blog/articulo-que-no-puedes-olvidar-en-tu-examen-para-la-guardia-civil.php
    Redirect 301 /blog-tecnicas-de-estudio-para-aprobar-las-oposiciones-de-gc.php https://www.academiapinto.es/blog/articulo-tecnicas-de-estudio-para-aprobar-las-oposiciones-de-gc.php
    Redirect 301 /blog-tienes-la-documentacion.php https://www.academiapinto.es/blog/articulo-tienes-la-documentacion.php
    
    Redirect 301 /noticia-Academia-Pinto-incrementa-las-horas-de-clases-online.php https://www.academiapinto.es/news/noticia-Academia-Pinto-incrementa-las-horas-de-clases-online.php
    Redirect 301 /noticia-instrucciones-rellenar-instancia-ingreso-guardia-civil.php https://www.academiapinto.es/news/noticia-instrucciones-rellenar-instancia-ingreso-guardia-civil.php
    Redirect 301 /noticia-oferta-curso-online-ingreso-Guardia-Civil.php https://www.academiapinto.es/news/noticia-oferta-curso-online-ingreso-Guardia-Civil.php
    
    # las de los empleos
    
    Redirect 301 /curso-a-distancia-ingreso-guardia-civil https://www.academiapinto.es/temario-de-ingreso-guardia-civil.php
    Redirect 301 /curso-a-distancia-ingreso-policia-nacional-escala-basica.php https://www.academiapinto.es/temario-de-ingreso-a-policia-nacional-escala-basica.php
    Redirect 301 /curso-a-distancia-cabo-guardia-civil.php https://www.academiapinto.es/temario-de-ascenso-a-cabo-guardia-civil.php
    Redirect 301 /curso-a-distancia-cabosub-guardia-civil.php https://www.academiapinto.es/temario-de-ascenso-a-cabo-guardia-civil.php
    Redirect 301 /curso-a-distancia-suboficial-guardia-civil.php https://www.academiapinto.es/temario-de-ascenso-a-suboficial-guardia-civil.php
    Redirect 301 /curso-a-distancia-oficial-guardia-civil.php https://www.academiapinto.es/temario-de-ascenso-a-oficial-guardia-civil.php
    
    # antiguas de JUAN arregladas
    # ahora cambiamos por las mejoras SEO las siguientes.
    
    Redirect 301 /clases-presenciales-de-ingreso-guardia-civil.php https://www.academiapinto.es/curso-de-ingreso-a-guardia-civil.php
    Redirect 301 /clases-online-de-ingreso-guardia-civil.php https://www.academiapinto.es/curso-online-de-ingreso-a-guardia-civil.php
    
    Redirect 301 /clases-online-de-cabo-guardia-civil.php https://www.academiapinto.es/curso-online-de-ascenso-a-cabo-guardia-civil.php
    Redirect 301 /curso-online-de-cabo-guardia-civil.php https://www.academiapinto.es/curso-online-de-ascenso-a-cabo-guardia-civil.php
    
    # seguimos.
    
    Redirect 301 /clases-online-de-oficial-guardia-civil.php https://www.academiapinto.es/curso-online-de-ascenso-a-oficial-guardia-civil.php
    Redirect 301 /clases-online-de-suboficial-guardia-civil.php https://www.academiapinto.es/curso-online-de-ascenso-a-suboficial-guardia-civil.php
    Redirect 301 /clases-presenciales-de-ascenso-a-oficial-guardia-civil.php https://www.academiapinto.es/curso-de-ascenso-a-oficial-guardia-civil.php
    Redirect 301 /clases-presenciales-de-ascenso-a-suboficial-guardia-civil.php https://www.academiapinto.es/curso-de-ascenso-a-suboficial-guardia-civil.php
    
    Redirect 301 /temario-Prueba-Conocimientos-Guardias-Jovenes-(Polillas).php https://www.academiapinto.es/temario-Guardias-Jovenes-(Polillas).php
    
    #parche NO-CNP
    Redirect 301 /curso-a-distancia-guardia-civil-y-policia-nacional.php https://www.academiapinto.es/curso-online-de-ingreso-a-guardia-civil.php
    Redirect 301 /temario-Guardias-Jovenes-(Polillas).php https://www.academiapinto.es/temario-Guardias-Jovenes-(Polillas).php
    
    
    # using root, not index.php ...
    # RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.academiapinto.es/ [L,R=301]
    # RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ https://www.academiapinto.es/ [L,R=301]
    # RewriteRule ^index\.html$ https://www.academiapinto.es/ [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^/temario-de-ingreso-guardia-civil$ https://www.academiapinto.es/temario-de-ingreso-guardia-civil.php [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
    
    # ... seguridades varias que interesan ...
    # If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
    # has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
    # and the request is for something within the component folder,
    # or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
    # requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
    # and the requested path and file doesn´t directly match a physical file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # and the requested path and file doesn´t directly match a physical folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
    
    # ... check for parameters ...
    
    # RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ /index.php [L]
    # RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ /index.php [L]
    # RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ /index.php [L]
    # RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ /index.php [L]
    # --- #RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?p1=ERROR_MODRW_ACCESS [L]
    
    ##############################################################
    
    # Enable GZIP
    <ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    </ifmodule>
    
    # Expires Headers - 2678400s = 31 days
    <ifmodule mod_expires.c>
      ExpiresActive On
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
      ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2678400 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2678400 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2678400 seconds"
      ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 518400 seconds"
      ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2678400 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2678400 seconds"
    </ifmodule>
    
    # Cache Headers
    <ifmodule mod_headers.c>
      # Cache specified files for 31 days 2678400
      <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$">
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
      </filesmatch>
      # Cache HTML files for a couple hours 7200
      <filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
      </filesmatch>
      # Cache PDFs for a day 86400
      <filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
      </filesmatch>
      # Cache Javascripts for 31 days 2678400
      <filesmatch "\.(js)$">
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private"
      </filesmatch>
    </ifmodule>
    
    ##############################################################
```

Thanks, i'm really desperated with this one.

Comment: Hi Manu, welcome.  Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048796/htaccess-add-php-to-everything-without-an-extension-already

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks, i tried this but doesn´t work. Can you take a look if you can to my htaccess? Regards

Comment: What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46471923/1114465 There are many questions with the same: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+extension+urls+htaccess Try to add the edit near the top of .htaccess.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add .php extension with URLs Using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46471618/add-php-extension-with-urls-using-htaccess)

Comment: And now, how i can get friendly URL's correctly? My .htaccess with the previous solution is in the first post

Comment: Hi, i tried a lot of things but i cant made friendly URL's in this htaccess. Someone can help? My htaccess is in the first post.